# Why do we need .htaccess in worpdress?

Tags: wordpress

I saw many WordPress themes. In every theme .htaccess file is included in the root folder. Why do we need this file? Is it necessary to keep this file?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, for apache configuration.
It uses for different url formats

More info [here.](https://codex.wordpress.org/htaccess)

Answer (score 1):

Like @Alicelf's answer, it's configuration file for Apache web server, make your website working, adding some feature like pretty URL, redirect, protect sensitive files,...

By the way, if you're using Nginx web server, it's fine to delete .htaccess files.

Answer (score 0):

I think @alicelf and @anh-tuan may have misunderstood your question. What you're asking is why are there `.htaccess` files in the theme's directories, right?

If so, it's to stop those directories being able to be browsed (by a browser or bot). If you look at the contents of the `.htaccess` files, they will probably have something like `deny from all` in them.